# Theorem Sato 30.1 subordinated levy process

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, levy-processes

Referring to Theorem 30.1 of Sato's book "Levy processes and Infinitely divisible distributions". In the proof, page 200, when he shows that the subordinated levy process has independent increments, is he covertly using the freezing lemma? I found the same proof in a thesis and it has a couple more passages involving the freezing lemma, conditioning to the whole vector of (Z(t{1}),...,Z(t_{n})). I'm not really getting why you should condition to get the result

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607972/do-you-know-this-result-about-conditional-expectation) the freezing lemma you're referring to? I'm hearing about this name for the first time, I don't call this result by any name actually. In any case, in what you pasted I don't see the definitions of $g,h$ so I'll have to see the text for that.

Comment: yes, it is! unfortunately it didn't let me upload more than one image in the post

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the image-related restrictions. Let me quickly take a look at Sato and the definitions I need to. +1

Comment: You're absolutely correct @Lys. If you look at the previous page to the one you've attached, which is part of the proof of Theorem $30.1$ and page $199$ of the book, then there is a reference to "Proposition $1.16$" , which is used to prove a one-dimensional subordination expectation lemma. Proposition $1.16$, which is on page $7$, is the freezing lemma, so it follows that it is required for the proof. As for why it's required, it converts expectations of functions of the subordinated process, to expectations involving functions of the subordinator, as in equation $(30.14)$.

Comment: I do not know of any other way of obtaining $(30.14)$ or the analogous statements on page $200$, other than conditioning on the subordinated process. It seems quite natural that if $Y_t = X_{Z_t}$ then conditioning on $Z_t$ brings out the nature of the process $X$.